My system crashed after attempting to unzip a .zip file
I'm running Ubuntu 24.04 from a persistent USB. While unzipping a 1.5 gigabyte file, my system crashed and displayed a black screen with a blinking cursor. I usually suspect USB corruption in such cases, but I'm unsure why unzipping a file would cause this. Any advice on preventing this in the future, or understanding why it happened, would be greatly appreciated.
Additionally, I was downloading Wine at the same time, which might be relevant.
After rebooting, many icons (e.g., WiFi, arrow, Bluetooth) were replaced with either a red square with a white circle and a dash or different versions of themselves. The system crashed again, possibly coincidentally when I tried to connect to WiFi. On subsequent reboots, the issue persisted and the system continued to crash.

Try again while monitoring your RAM usage.

did you unzip it directly to your USB drive ?

(replying to dominix) That's what it does automatically, as it's a persistent drive.

To answer user535733, I monitered it and it stayed a completely flay line at right below 50%.

It also didn't crash it, so I'm starting to think that it might be unrelated that I was unzipping something
